# How do I display all the data in categories on y-axis in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to display on the y-axis of the data through the **categories** property. I pass an array as I saw in some examples

```
initLapChart() {
hcharts.chart(this.div.nativeElement, {
  chart: {
     ...
  },
  yAxis: {
    categories: ["0:20", "0:30", "0:40", "1:00", "1:15"],
    reversed: true,
    tickPixelInterval: 50,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    ... 
  },
  ...
}
```

but it only shows me the first two values, why?

Comment: We need more information. A single snippet does not help as you do not include how your data is formatted or any other pertinent details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show all of your categories, whether you have data for them or not, you just need to set your axis min and max values:

```
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 4,
        reversed: true,
        tickInterval: 1,
        categories: ['0:20', '0:30', '0:40', '1:00', '1:15'],
        labels: {
            step: 1
        }
    },
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/y3ut4jdv/1/

Or you can do it programmatically if you define your categories up front:

```
var categories = ['0:20', '0:30', '0:40', '1:00', '1:15'], 
    yMax = categories.length -1;
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/y3ut4jdv/2/

Answer (score 0):

The elements in `categories` array are indexed from `0` to `categories.length - 1`, so the first element from the array represents value 0 on yAxis, the second, value 1, etc. If you want to display them all, you need to set `tickInterval` and `labels.step` properties with value 1.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.step

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6qp0v887/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not exactly what I want. In the link I shows exactly my situation. I would like to see "0:30" and "0:20" as well as others who are in categories just enough.
exmaple:
[http://jsfiddle.net/y3ut4jdv/](http://jsfiddle.net/y3ut4jdv/)

Comment: When I enter your link it only shows 'Example Domain'. As for the problem, you need to have enough categories to display. In my example it shows only five categories elements because this is the total number of provided categories. Recreate your problem in a working JSFiddle demo.